# Algebra of a transfer function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out how I would rearrange, eliminate and factorise the equation marked A (Figure 1) to get the equation marked B (Figure 1).

Context: This is a transfer function that has been derived from a jacket cooled tank. There is no chemical reaction occurring in the tank. I understand how they derived the transfer functions and I understand that the (500s +1) present in equation B comes from the time domain of the second equation (theta w0) in equation A. However, I've attempted to back-substitute these equations for hours but I don't understand where the numbers come from at all.

[image: Figure 1]

This is my working:

Equation 1$$ \theta_{w0}(s) = \frac{(4200s + 2.52)}{(1.68)} \theta_{P0}(s) - \frac{0.84}{1.68} \theta_{P1}(s) + \frac{84}{1.68} Fp(s) $$

Equation 2$$ \theta_{w0}(s) = \frac{0.42}{(500s+1)} \theta_{W1}(s) - \frac{168}{(500s+1)} Fw(s) + \frac{1.68}{(500s+1)} \theta_{P0}(s) $$

Sub equation 2 into 1:

$$ \frac{0.42}{(500s+1)} \theta_{W1}(s) - \frac{168}{(500s+1)} Fw(s) + \frac{1.68}{(500s+1)} \theta_{P0}(s) = \frac{(4200s + 2.52)}{(1.68)} \theta_{P0}(s) - \frac{0.84}{1.68} \theta_{P1}(s) + \frac{84}{1.68} Fp(s) $$

Making $$ \theta_{P0}(s) $$ the subject gives:

$$ \frac{(4200s + 2.52)}{(1.68)}(500s+1)\theta_{P0}(s)- 1.68\theta_{P0}(s)= \frac{0.84}{1.68} \theta_{P1}(s)(500s+1)- \frac{84}{1.68} Fp(s)(500s+1) + 0.42\theta_{w1}(s)-168\ Fw(s) $$

And then I'm stuck, I cannot condense the equation into equation B.. I feel like I've made a very basic calculation error but I really cannot pinpoint where.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Hi Jose, sorry about that I've added some context to the question now. I don't really know how else to describe the issue I'm having, it's more algebra and basic mathematics than anything else.

Comment: You do exactly what it says to do: first, you eliminate $\theta_{W0}(s)$, then, you rearrange, and then, you factor. So, which of these is giving you trouble?

Comment: Here's an example of what you might say "I take the first equation, and move $\theta_{w0}$ to the left and everything else to the right, getting $$1.68 
 \theta_{w0}(s) = 0.84 \theta_{P1}(s) + 84 F_P(s) - (4200s + 2.52)\theta_{P0}(s);$$ I then divide through by $1.68$ to get ..."

Comment: @JohnHughes - Thanks John. Following from what you said I isolated w0(s) from the first equation in A and then I divided the second equation by (500s + 1), which is the time domain of the second equation in A. This makes θw0(s) the subject of both equation systems. Then I substitute equation 2 in part A into equation 1 in part A, eliminating  θw0(s). After this I multiply through by (500s +1) and I rearrange to make θP0(s) the subject and this is where I'm stuck. I cannot get the same numbers shown in equation B. (Sorry for the messy reply, I'm having trouble explaining myself).

Comment: The good news is that you don't **have** to explain yourself --- you just have to edit your question (click on "edit" below the question itself) and start adding equations, perhaps with a little text between them to show us what you've tried, and where you actually got stuck. As an example of how to write equations, for the one I wrote above, I typed this: `$$ 1.68 \theta_{w0}(s) = 0.849 \theta_{P1}(s) + 84 F_P(s) - (4200)s + 2.52) \theta_{P0}(s);$$;` if I'd wanted to add more, I'd have written something like this: `$$a = b \\ c = d \\ e = f + g$$` producing  $$a = b \\ c = d \\ e = f + g.$$

Comment: @JohnHughes - Thanks again John. I've never used MathJax before but that was easier than I thought! I hope this gives a better explanation of my problem.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks for the reply Gerry. I've added my working to the original question to demonstrate where I'm getting stuck. Hope that makes it clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I'm going to make it easier to answer by replacing some names with shorter names: 
\begin{align}
A &= \theta_{P0}(s) \\
B &= \theta_{W0}(s) \\
C &= \theta_{P1}(s) \\
D &= \theta_{W1}(s) \\
E &= F_P(s) \\
F &= F_w(s) 
\end{align}
Now the equations become
\begin{align}
(4200s + 2.52) A &= 0.84 C + 84 E + 1.68 B \\
(1050s + 2.1) B &= 0.420 D - 168 F + 1.68 A
\end{align}
Solve for $B$ in the first equation:
\begin{align}
-1.68B &= -(4200s + 2.52) A + 0.84 C + 84 E\\
1.68B &= (4200s + 2.52) A - 0.84 C - 84 E\\
B& = \frac{4200s + 2.52}{1.68} A - \frac{0.84}{1.68} C - \frac{84}{1.68} E\\
B &= (2500s + 1.5) A - \frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\\
\end{align}
Now substitute that in the second equation:
\begin{align}
(1050s + 2.1) B &= 0.420 D - 168 F + 1.68 A\\
(1050s + 2.1)\left( (2500s + 1.5) A - \frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)  &= 0.420 D - 168 F + 1.68 A\\
(1050s + 2.1)\left( (2500s + 1.5) A \right) - \left( (1050s + 2.1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  &= 0.420 D - 168 F + 1.68 A\\
(1050s + 2.1)\left( (2500s + 1.5) A \right) &=  \left( (1050s + 21)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.420 D - 168 F + 1.68 A\\
2.1(500s + 1)\left( (2500s + 1.5) A \right) &=  \left( (1050s + 2.1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.420 D - 168 F + 1.68 A\\
(500s + 1) (2500s + 1.5) A  &=  \left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + \frac{0.420}{2.1} D - \frac{168}{2.1}F + \frac{1.68}{2.1} A\\
(500s + 1) (2500s + 1.5) A  &=  \left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2 D - 80F + 0.8 A\\
(500s + 1) (2500s + 1.5) A  - 0.8 A &=  \left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2 D - 80F\\
1250000 s^2 A+ 3250 sA + 1.5A - 0.8A &= \left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2 D - 80F\\
1250000 s^2A + 3250 sA + 0.7A &= \left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2 D - 80F\\
\end{align}
Now the equation we're trying to match has the coefficient of $A$ written in the form $(Ps + 1) (Qs + 1)$, so let's divide through by $0.7$ to give that some hope of happening:

\begin{align}
1250000 s^2A + 3250 sA + 0.7A &= \left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2 D - 80F\\
1785714.29 s^2A + 4642.86 sA + A &= \frac{1}{0.7}\left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2857 D - 114.2857 F\\
\end{align}
The quadratic on the left has two roots: 
$$
r_{1,2} = \frac{-4642.86 \pm \sqrt{(4642.86)^2 - 4\cdot 1785714.29 \cdot 1}}{2\cdot 1785714.29} \\
\approx -.000236986, -0.0023630
$$
so we can write it in the form
$$
(\frac{1}{-r_1} s + 1) (\frac{1}{-r_2} s + 1)
$$
because the constant coefficient is $1$. So what are the negative root-reciprocals?

$$
\frac{1}{-r_{1,2}} = 423.19, 4219.7
$$
Rewriting using these gives

\begin{align}
1785714.29 s^2A + 4642.86 sA + A &= \frac{1}{0.7}\left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2857 D - 114.2857 F\\
(4219.7s + 1)(423.9s +  1) &= \frac{1}{0.7}\left( (500s + 1)\left(\frac{1}{2} C - 50 E\right)\right)  + 0.2857 D - 114.2857 F\\
(4219.7s + 1)(423.9s +  1) &= 0.7143 (500s + 1) C - 71.43 (500s + 1)E   + 0.2857 D - 114.2857 F\\
\end{align}
which is surprisingly close to what you were looking for. The difference in decimals probably arose from me (or the authors) using numerical approximations (vs exact arithmetic) at different times in the solving process. And the sign error on the coefficient of $E$ is probably my mistake somewhere along the way, but I leave it to you to work out.